# Calculate the number of rides for users by day_of_week by adding Count of trip_id to Values

Tags: google-sheets, count, average, data-analysis

Hello I am trying to calculate the number of rides for users by day of the week by trip ID but instead it's coming up as Averaging the number as if I am adding all numbers and dividing by the number of entries. I want to treat the trip ID as a count not avg all the number because then I think that won't reflect the number of rides per week. Can anyone help me with a formula on how to count the number of rides per week with these dates. I put an picture example of how I tried to do it but it is not working, and cannot find a solution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZgYl.png)

[image]

Comment: Can you share a sample/copy of your spreadsheet with expected result so we can easily replicate and provide you with an accurate/working solution or alternate answer if any. Please remove any sensitive data.

Answer (score 1):

```
CountD(trip_id)
```

And you plot against Days of Week

Comment: How would I find the average per week using the dates in the data? Is CountD a formula in excel desktop because it doesn't seem like it.

Comment: Use COUNTIF instead of AVERAGE OF, COUNTD is for Tableau

Comment: I have no idea if what I got is correct, but I used Countif. Thank you. How would I be able to test this on a smaller scale?

Comment: Use filters then, reduce the amount of rows, but just know that it's correct

Comment: Thank you this will make sense for testing because it is the average of count not actually Avg ALL NUMBERS THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I ended up using Countif.

[image]